# Downloading image from URL using Python giving corrupted results

Tags: python, image, download, urllib, python-requests

I'm writing a script to download a Steam profile picture from its URL, as provided by the Steam API.  Regardless of the method that I use, I'm getting corrupted results:

[image: Example with corrupted and original images]

[Steam's link to the original image](http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ad/adec76ed86e8ffa892d847c8e619262d30e74e32_full.jpg).

Using the "requests" library:

```
avatar = open(avatarName, 'wb')
avatar.write(requests.get(avatarURL).content)
avatar.close()
```

as well as:

```
avatar = requests.get(avatarURL)
with open(avatarName, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(avatar.content)
```

And using the "urllib" library:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(avatarURL, avatarName)
```

as well as:

```
avatar = urllib.URLopener()
avatar.retrieve(avatarURL, avatarName)
```

And using wget directly on the link (note that this is outside Python, just from the terminal):

```
wget http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ad/adec76ed86e8ffa892d847c8e619262d30e74e32_full.jpg
```

Since it's a corruption issue I was thinking it might have to do with setting/not setting the binary flag when I open the file object.  <s>Another method I haven't tried yet is importing OS commands and using wget to download the file and then working from there.</s>  wget gives the corrupted result as well.

Interestingly enough, it appears that every method used results in images that are corrupted in exactly the same way every time.

I haven't used urllib2 yet (here), simply because most of the Q&A's I've been checking have been using urllib.

Comment: What's the URL specifically (or another similar one)? Without being able to test this, I can not help you.

Comment: does wget work ok for this url?

Comment: @sigmavirus24 The example image is [here.](http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/ad/adec76ed86e8ffa892d847c8e619262d30e74e32_full.jpg)

Comment: @Antigluk wget fails as well; I've edited the question to include that information.

Comment: All methods and wget work fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @ton1c said everything worked for him, I tried running wget from another system and it worked just fine.  I'm using Filezilla to transfer files to/from my server, so I checked the images *actually on the server* by navigating to them with a browser and all of them rendered normally.  Apparently downloading them to my computer with Filezilla caused the corruption.  That's a different problem, but a minor one that I'll figure out on my own.